# appendix formatting: section number before \appendixname

Tags: sectioning, table-of-contents, formatting, appendices

Here is my situation:

## Source code

in preamble:

```
\usepackage[title,titletoc]{appendix}
\renewcommand{\appendixname}{priedas}
```

in document:

```
\begin{appendices}

  \section{Tekstai}
  Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem, quia voluptas sit, aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos, qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt, neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum, quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt, ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem.

\end{appendices}
```

## Output document

in toc:

```
priedas A  Tekstai ......................... 20
```

in document:

```
priedas A  Tekstai
```

## Wanted output document

in toc:

```
A priedas  Tekstai ......................... 20
```

in document:

```
A priedas  Tekstai
```

Comment: Please add to your question a [minimal working example](http://www.minimalbeispiel.de/mini-en.html) reproducing the behaviour mentioned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using the `article` document class, then you can achieve the desired result with the help of the `titlesec` and `titletoc` packages; a little example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{titletoc}
\usepackage[title,titletoc]{appendix}
\renewcommand{\appendixname}{priedas}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\section{Test regular section}

\begin{appendices}
\titlecontents{section}
  [1.7em]{}{\contentslabel{1.7em}\appendixname\ }{\hspace*{-1.7em}}
  {\titlerule*[1pc]{}\contentspage}
\titleformat{\section}
  {\normalfont\Large\bfseries}{\thesection\ \appendixname}{1em}{}

  \section{Tekstai}
  Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem, quia voluptas sit, aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos, qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt, neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum, quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt, ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem.

\end{appendices}

\end{document}
```

With minor modifications, this will also work with the `scrartcl` document class. However, this approach will fail with `amsart`.

Comment: Good answer. By the way, for my case I altered: for the toc leader dots - titlerule to "...\titlerule*[1.5mm]{.}..."; for a nicer spacing - titlecontents to "...titlecontents{section}
  [0em]{}{\thecontentslabel\ ...". Also, my documentclass is "article". I thank you again!